How to create a custom component on redhawk 3.0.0?
I have created a basic component of getting two inputs which multiplies those inputs and pushes that data into the packet.
After successfully building the component, I want to export it to the SDR root. While exporting the component, it shows an error like 'Problem loading SDR Root' on Redhawk Explorer.
Please help me to solve this.
I had 'no match for operand= error in using the vectors. I had overcome that by copying the Data Buffers got from the dataFloat_in port's packets to the float type vector variables. Now it is compiled without errors. But I don't know how to solve this SDR Root loading error.
